# Intellij IDEA - How to disable automatic plugin update

Tags: intellij-idea, pmd

Whenever you hit 'the check for update' button, IntelliJ checks for IDE update and starts by checking and updating all your active plugins.

The point is that I use a pretty crooked plugin which only works for me in an old version (a release from last year).
To be more specific, I'm talking about '[QA Plug PMD](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4596)' which is not compatible with my imported sonar rules in its last version.
Actually, QA Plug PMD's last version is based on PMD 5.0.x and I need QA Plug PMD's 2012 version which is based on PMD 4.3.

In summary, when the QA Plug PMD plugin gets updated, my coding rules are all reseted because the plugin is not backwards-compatible.

That being said, I need to know if there's a way I can tell IntelliJ not to care about **this** specific plugin during its update process and leave it alone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would probably be to **not** install it from the plugin repository. Try to install it from disk instead. Download it from the link you provided instead (the zip file will be downloaded):

[image]

Then choose to `Install plugin from disk...` instead:

[image]

And then point to the `pmd.zip` file:

[image]

---

**Edit**

During the update you will get a question whether you want to update the plugins as well and you can always uncheck that plugin:

[image]

---

**Edit2**

Make sure that you don't have the `Check for updates in channel` checked. That might help you out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did install the plugin from disk, as if I had installed plugin from 'browse repositories' feature it would have downloaded the very last version =)

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid You can always choose to not install a later plugin. Updated my answer. Or are you looking for a more permanent solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, whether we install a plugin from a zip file or by using automatic remote downloading ('browse repositories'), it is taken into account during IntelliJ's update process.
I have no memory of any kind of dialog from IntelliJ asking me to accept or discard new plugin updates. Neither globally nor specifically.

I even plugged Fiddler between IntelliJ and Internet during automatic update. The last version (zip file) is properly downloaded and installed in background. All I get then is the final dialog asking to postpone or perform IDE restart to finalize the new installation.

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid What version of IntelliJ are you using? Is it Ultimate or Community edition? Also, try to make a manual update and see if you get the popup window. Maybe it is not coming up if you have automatic updates turned on. I updated my last screenshot again to show you that I have two plugins with old versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. I just tried it again and now I get the dialog window in which I can check or not to update each plugin.

In fact, I don't get this dialog window when IntelliJ finds an IDEA update.
Actually, I upgraded from 12.1.3 to 12.1.4 (Ulitmate) and all plugins included QA Plug PMD got forcibly updated and the said confirm dialog was not shown.

But once my IntelliJ was up to date (12.1.4), 'Check for update...' shows the wanted dialog you screen-shot !

Good to know, I'll only have to manually reinstall back the old version from pmd.zip after an IDE upgrade.

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid Great. I added another screenshot and I don't know if you already tried that out. You shouldn't get any automatic updates if you uncheck that box and it might help you. You'll have to check for updates manually instead.

Answer (score 5):

> Goto File -> Setting -> Appearance& Behaviour>System Setting->
>   Updates->Uncheck the Automatic uppadte checkbox.

Tada.. Done.

Danke,
Rahul